# Store value in ROM

Tags: android, android-storage

I want to store my value in ROM of phone, here is how I want store:

1. When my app open, I want to get the value which stored before
2. When my app is running, I have to store value whenever the event clicked
3. When my app open in the second times, I can get my value in the first times

My value is of type `List<String>`. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you need this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: for persistence in Android start from here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html